# How to throw exception from java streams after satisfying a filter condition

Tags: java, exception, java-stream

I have list of response from a rest WS. This list contains "Response" objects in which each object contains e field called "tokenExpiry". If any one of these token expiry is < currentTimeInMillis , then I have to throw an exception

Pseudo code something like this

```
list.stream().filter(response -> response.tokenExpiry < currentTimeInMillis)
```

then throw `new Exception`.

Comment: @GhostCat Not a duplicate; an XY.

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter` for Responses `response.tokenExpiry<currentTimeInMillis` and `findFirst` to break stream after first match, then use `ifPresent` to throw exception

```
list.stream().filter(response->response.tokenExpiry<currentTimeInMillis).findFirst().ifPresent(s-> {
        throw new RuntimeException(s);
    });
```

Or you can also use `anyMatch` which returns `boolean`

```
boolean res = list.stream().anyMatch(response->response.tokenExpiry<currentTimeInMillis)
if(res) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
 }
```

Or simple `forEach` is also better choice

```
list.forEach(response-> {
     if(response.tokenExpiry<currentTimeInMillis) {
           throw new RuntimeException();
      }
   });
```

Comment: Don't forget about `anyMatch()`.

Comment: anyMatch will return boolean right not an Optional @chrylis

Comment: Correct, but if you don't need the matching element, you can eliminate the fluff. I'll make a note of the differences in our answers.

Comment: Also, `findAny` is nearly always good enough and sometimes more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Java Streams have a specific method for checking whether any element of the stream matches a condition:

```
if (list.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.tokenExpiry < currentTimeInMillis)) {
    // throw your exception
}
```

This is a bit simpler and more efficient, but it doesn't provide you the actual value, which @Deadpool's `find` version does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
if(list.stream().filter(response -> (response.tokenExpiry<currentTimeInMillis).findAny().isPresent()) {
    throw new CustomExeption("message");
}
```